# react-bootstrap-table-next on selectRow selects all Rows

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

**Requirement** : To change the background colour of row on selection:

```
**npm package**: "react-bootstrap-table-next": {
            "version": "4.0.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-bootstrap-table-next/-/react-bootstrap-table-next-4.0.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-uKxC73qUdUfusRf2uzDfMiF9LvTG5vuhTZa0lbAgHWSLLLaKTsI0iHf1e4+c7gP71q8dFsp7StvkP65SxC1JRg==",
            "requires": {
                "classnames": "^2.2.5",
                "react-transition-group": "^4.2.0",
                "underscore": "1.9.1"
            }
        },
```

**Code:**

```
const selectRow = {
    mode: 'checkBox',
    // hideSelectColumn: false,
    clickToSelect: true,
    // clickToEdit: true,
    color: '#def3ff',

  };

 <BootstrapTable
                  mode="radio"
                  size="sm"
                  className="small"
                  bordered={false}
                  striped
                  keyField="id"
                  data={historyData}
                  columns={columnsHistoryTable}
                  rowEvents={historyRowEvent}
                  selectRow={selectRow}

                />
```

Problem: On doing this all the rows are getting selected,I need to change the colour of only the selected row

Answer (score 0):

```
  const selectRow = {

    mode: 'checkBox',

    clickToSelect: true,

    style: { background: '#def3ff' },
};
```

Or see this link above:
https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Row%20Selection&selectedStory=Selection%20Background%20Color&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

Comment: can we have other options for mode instead of 'checkbox' only? like I have to use 'hyperlink' for mode.

Comment: You can try to hide the column of checkbox like in this example https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Row%20Selection&selectedStory=Hide%20Selection%20Column&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel, and edit the row with css to give the form you want, if you want hyperlink or whatever, but in all the examples that i see i only find two modes 'checkbox' and 'radio'.